# How do I stop appache.commons.logging from spamming System.out?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, clojure, apache-commons-logging

I am writing a clojure app that uses Amazon S3. It is using the standard amazonaws library, under [this wrapper](https://github.com/weavejester/clj-aws-s3/blob/master/src/aws/sdk/s3.clj). For some reason, it is logging to System.out a ton of DEBUG info, including but not limited to the entire binary file I am sending to S3.

As of writing this, I have tried setting up a log4j.properties file:

```
# Direct log messages to NULL gdmnt
log4j.appender.devnull=org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender
log4j.rootLogger=fatal, devnull


log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=ERROR
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.content=ERROR
org.appache.http=ERROR
org.appache.http.wire=ERROR
org.appache.http.headers=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws=WARN
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.request=WARN
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.http=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire = WARN
```

Yet it still sends DEBUG info. Yes, log4j is on my classpath. Here is a printout of my classpath filtered for log4j

```
 /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.7/log4j-api-2.7.jar
/Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.7/log4j-core-2.7.jar
```

Here is an example of the logs produced when I send just a simple string to an S3 bucket.

```
    17:53:52.092 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG c.a.internal.config.InternalConfig - Configuration override awssdk_config_override.json not found.
17:53:52.126 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG c.a.services.s3.internal.S3Signer - Calculated string to sign:
"PUT

text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Tue, 10 Jan 2017 22:53:52 GMT
/eden-cybernetics-voice/key"
17:53:52.225 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG com.amazonaws.request - Sending Request: PUT https://eden-cybernetics-voice.s3.amazonaws.com /key Headers: (Authorization: AWS YA,FUCKTHAT=, User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.7.5 Mac_OS_X/10.11.5 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.102-b14/1.8.0_102, Content-Length: 3, Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 22:53:52 GMT, Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8, ) 
17:53:52.326 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://eden-cybernetics-voice.s3.amazonaws.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
17:53:52.356 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://eden-cybernetics-voice.s3.amazonaws.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 50]
17:53:52.889 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to eden-cybernetics-voice.s3.amazonaws.com:443
17:53:53.145 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
17:53:53.147 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
17:53:53.148 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestProxyAuthentication - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
17:53:53.149 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG c.a.http.impl.client.SdkHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
17:53:53.150 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: PUT /key HTTP/1.1
17:53:53.151 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "PUT /key HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.153 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Host: eden-cybernetics-voice.s3.amazonaws.com[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.154 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Authorization: AWS YA, FUCKTHAT=[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.155 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.7.5 Mac_OS_X/10.11.5 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.102-b14/1.8.0_102[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.155 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 22:53:52 GMT[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.156 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.156 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Length: 3[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.157 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.157 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Expect: 100-continue[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.157 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.158 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> PUT /key HTTP/1.1
17:53:53.158 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Host: eden-cybernetics-voice.s3.amazonaws.com
17:53:53.158 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Authorization: AWS YA, I AM NOT SHOWING YOU THIS=
17:53:53.159 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.7.5 Mac_OS_X/10.11.5 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.102-b14/1.8.0_102
17:53:53.159 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 22:53:52 GMT
17:53:53.159 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
17:53:53.159 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Length: 3
17:53:53.159 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
17:53:53.160 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Expect: 100-continue
17:53:53.209 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.213 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.214 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
17:53:53.214 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
17:53:53.215 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "key"
17:53:53.252 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.253 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "x-amz-id-2: KxZ8+cp4/BDEm4hdEjaVI/8tUaz0RRh6hcM041BB5pMlHXGXTAjJS3hA3VojH6H4UlleHmD2HSE=[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.253 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "x-amz-request-id: F83687CB8CDEB189[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.254 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 22:53:54 GMT[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.254 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "ETag: "3c6e0b8a9c15224a8228b9a98ca1531d"[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.255 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.256 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Server: AmazonS3[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.257 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
17:53:53.258 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
17:53:53.258 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
17:53:53.258 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << x-amz-id-2: KxZ8+cp4/BDEm4hdEjaVI/8tUaz0RRh6hcM041BB5pMlHXGXTAjJS3hA3VojH6H4UlleHmD2HSE=
17:53:53.259 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << x-amz-request-id: F83687CB8CDEB189
17:53:53.259 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 22:53:54 GMT
17:53:53.259 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << ETag: "3c6e0b8a9c15224a8228b9a98ca1531d"
17:53:53.259 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Content-Length: 0
17:53:53.260 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Server: AmazonS3
17:53:53.265 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG c.a.http.impl.client.SdkHttpClient - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
17:53:53.276 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG com.amazonaws.request - Received successful response: 200, AWS Request ID: F83687CB8CDEB189
17:53:53.277 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: 0][route: {s}->https://eden-cybernetics-voice.s3.amazonaws.com:443] can be kept alive indefinitely
17:53:53.278 [nREPL-worker-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://eden-cybernetics-voice.s3.amazonaws.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 50]
#object[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectResult 0x3822e74d "com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectResult@3822e74d"]
17:54:51.712 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
17:55:51.793 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
17:55:51.881 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Connection 0.0.0.0:61322<->52.216.80.64:443 closed
17:56:51.896 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
17:57:51.909 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
17:58:51.918 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
17:59:51.929 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECOND
```

My current strategy is to first find out if appache.commons.logging is even using log4j, but I don't know how to do that.

Next, I want to check that log4j is loading in the log4j.properties file.

Is this a good strategy? How do I accomplish it? Do you know another strategy?

S3 under clojure is unusable as is.

Here is my summarized project.clj:

```
 (defproject voice "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.5"]
            [lein-figwheel "0.5.8"]]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]

                 [org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core "2.7"]
                 [org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api "2.7"]

                 ;browser repl
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.293"]
                 [lein-figwheel "0.5.8"]
                 [figwheel-sidecar "0.5.8"]

                 ;explicitly get the right version
                 [instaparse "1.4.0"]

                 ;for the trainer
                 [org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core "0.7.1"]
                 [org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-ui_2.10 "0.7.1"]
                 ;[org.nd4j/nd4j-cuda-7.5 "0.7.1"] ;for cuda
                 [org.nd4j/nd4j-native "0.7.1"]

                 ;for the sampler
                 [clojure-opennlp "0.3.3"]
                 [compojure "1.5.1"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.5"]
                 [http-kit "2.2.0"]
                 [garden "1.3.2"]

                 ;;for the sampler client
                 [jayq "2.5.4"]
                 [cljs-ajax "0.5.8"]


                 ;for the database
                 [korma "0.4.3"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4.1212"]
                 [clj-aws-s3 "0.3.10" :exclusions [joda-time]]


                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]]
  :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[alembic "0.3.2"]
                                  [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.10"]
                                  [com.cemerick/piggieback "0.2.1"]]}}
  :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [cemerick.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]}

  :jvm-opts ["-Dlog4j.debug=true"]

  :cljsbuild {
              :builds [{
                        :source-paths ["src/cljs/"]
                        :id "dev"
                        :figwheel {:websocket-host "localhost"}
                        :compiler {
                                   :main "voice.sampler"
                                   :asset-path "js/out"
                                   :output-to "resources/public/js/main.js"
                                   :output-dir "resources/public/js/out"}}]})
```

Here is my fullish classpath:

```
    /Users/collinbell/voice/test/
    /Users/collinbell/voice/src/
    /Users/collinbell/voice/dev-resources
    /Users/collinbell/voice/resources/
    /Users/collinbell/voice/target/classes/
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.4/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-jackson/0.7.1/nd4j-jackson-0.7.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/net/jodah/typetools/0.4.3/typetools-0.4.3.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/flatland/classlojure/0.7.0/classlojure-0.7.0.jar

    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/mchange/mchange-commons-java/0.2.11/mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/jackson/0.7.1/jackson-0.7.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/lein-as-resource/lein-as-resource/2.5.0/lein-as-resource-2.5.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.1/commons-lang3-3.3.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/ring-cors/ring-cors/0.1.8/ring-cors-0.1.8.jar
 /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.analyzer/0.6.9/tools.analyzer-0.6.9.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.7.5/aws-java-sdk-1.7.5.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/ring/ring-core/1.5.0/ring-core-1.5.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-common/0.7.1/nd4j-common-0.7.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/leptonica/1.73-1.2/leptonica-1.73-1.2-macosx-x86_64.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/play/play-functional_2.10/2.4.6/play-functional_2.10-2.4.6.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/google/jsinterop/jsinterop-annotations/1.0.0/jsinterop-annotations-1.0.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/collections/eclipse-collections-api/7.1.0/eclipse-collections-api-7.1.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/config/1.3.0/config-1.3.0.jar
   /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/stuartsierra/dependency/0.2.0/dependency-0.2.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/leptonica/1.73-1.2/leptonica-1.73-1.2.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/cemerick/piggieback/0.2.1/piggieback-0.2.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor/2.5.3/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.5.3.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/collections/eclipse-collections/7.1.0/eclipse-collections-7.1.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.5/xz-1.5.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/compojure/compojure/1.5.1/compojure-1.5.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-core/3.1.1/imageio-core-3.1.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.4/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.12/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/opencv/3.1.0-1.2/opencv-3.1.0-1.2-macosx-x86_64.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/net/cgrand/sjacket/0.1.1/sjacket-0.1.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/collections/eclipse-collections-forkjoin/7.1.0/eclipse-collections-forkjoin-7.1.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1/httpclient-4.5.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/3.0.2-1.2/ffmpeg-3.0.2-1.2.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/agrona/Agrona/0.5.4/Agrona-0.5.4.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/play/play-exceptions/2.4.6/play-exceptions-2.4.6.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/stuartsierra/component/0.3.1/component-0.3.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/studio/org.apache.commons.codec/1.8/org.apache.commons.codec-1.8.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/cider/cider-nrepl/0.15.0-SNAPSHOT/cider-nrepl-0.15.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/3.0.2-1.2/ffmpeg-3.0.2-1.2-windows-x86_64.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8/commons-compress-1.8.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/clj-aws-s3/clj-aws-s3/0.3.10/clj-aws-s3-0.3.10.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.4.1212/postgresql-9.4.1212.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/leptonica/1.73-1.2/leptonica-1.73-1.2-linux-x86_64.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-all/4.2/asm-all-4.2.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/twelvemonkeys/common/common-image/3.1.1/common-image-3.1.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/garden/garden/1.3.2/garden-1.3.2.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-psd/3.1.1/imageio-psd-3.1.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-buffer/0.7.1/nd4j-buffer-0.7.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.10.4.Final/netty-3.10.4.Final.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/data.json/0.2.6/data.json-0.2.6.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/0.7.1/deeplearning4j-core-0.7.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/data.priority-map/0.0.7/data.priority-map-0.0.7.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-bmp/3.1.1/imageio-bmp-3.1.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/cljs-ajax/cljs-ajax/0.5.8/cljs-ajax-0.5.8.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.reader/1.0.0-beta3/tools.reader-1.0.0-beta3.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/tcrawley/dynapath/0.2.5/dynapath-0.2.5.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-api/0.7.1/nd4j-api-0.7.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.10/lombok-1.16.10.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/yahoo/platform/yui/yuicompressor/2.4.8/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.12/snakeyaml-1.12.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/crypto-random/crypto-random/1.2.0/crypto-random-1.2.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/mapdb/elsa/3.0.0-M5/elsa-3.0.0-M5.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-ui-model/0.7.1/deeplearning4j-ui-model-0.7.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/cheshire/cheshire/5.5.0/cheshire-5.5.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.nrepl/0.2.12/tools.nrepl-0.2.12.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/annotations/2.0.1/annotations-2.0.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp/0.7.1/deeplearning4j-nlp-0.7.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/cognitect/transit-java/0.8.311/transit-java-0.8.311.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/mapdb/mapdb/3.0.2/mapdb-3.0.2.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.7/log4j-core-2.7.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/mozilla/rhino/1.7R5/rhino-1.7R5.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/strictly-specking-standalone/strictly-specking-standalone/0.1.1/strictly-specking-standalone-0.1.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/play/play-iteratees_2.10/2.4.6/play-iteratees_2.10-2.4.6.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/twelvemonkeys/common/common-io/3.1.1/common-io-3.1.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.7.1/nd4j-native-0.7.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/http-kit/http-kit/2.2.0/http-kit-2.2.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.2.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.2.1.Final.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/leptonica/1.73-1.2/leptonica-1.73-1.2-windows-x86_64.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/msgpack/msgpack/0.6.10/msgpack-0.6.10.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/clojure-opennlp/clojure-opennlp/0.3.3/clojure-opennlp-0.3.3.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/net/cgrand/parsley/0.9.3/parsley-0.9.3.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.0.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.0.3.Final.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.1/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/net/incongru/watchservice/barbary-watchservice/1.0/barbary-watchservice-1.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/19.0/guava-19.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/mchange/c3p0/0.9.5.2/c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.cache/0.6.5/core.cache-0.6.5.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/3.0.2-1.2/ffmpeg-3.0.2-1.2-linux-x86_64.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/3.0.2-1.2/ffmpeg-3.0.2-1.2-macosx-x86_64.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/net/sf/jwordnet/jwnl/1.3.3/jwnl-1.3.3.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-java8-compat_2.10/0.3.0/scala-java8-compat_2.10-0.3.0.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpasyncclient/4.1.1/httpasyncclient-4.1.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-jpeg/3.1.1/imageio-jpeg-3.1.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/clout/clout/2.1.2/clout-2.1.2.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/clj-stacktrace/clj-stacktrace/0.2.8/clj-stacktrace-0.2.8.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/play/twirl-api_2.10/1.1.1/twirl-api_2.10-1.1.1.jar
    /Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/src.zip
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
/Users/collinbell/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.7/log4j-api-2.7.jar
```

Comment: the log4j.properties file needs to be on your classpath, is it?

Comment: Yes. See, the second block of code. It is a 2 liner.

Comment: The 2 lines you posted show that the log4j jars are in your classpath, but you also need to have the file log4j.properties in your classpath for things to work. Also, check if the logging configuration you posted works for log4j 2.7 ... Older versions had a similar configuration but they were different.

Comment: Pass -Dlog4j.debug to see what configuration is being used. Without this you can never be sure if your cinfig is even used.

Comment: Yes, log4j.properties is in my class path. I am not entirely sure how to pass `-Dlog4j.debug` due to this being clojure, but I will try to figure it out.

Comment: I set `-Dlog4j.debug=true` in the `jvm-opts` section of my project.clj file, so I think it is now starting clojure using that java option, however, I am not seeing any log4j debug information at all.

Comment: please add your full classpath and a summarised project.clj to the question

Comment: Ok. I added those things. I couldn't get the complete class path. There was simply too much. The log4j.properties is in /src

Comment: I can't even get that project.clj to start a repl. I would *strongly* recommend against using that clj-aws-s3 wrapper, it hasn't been updated in over 2 years. Clojure interop is really very good and using the amazon libaries directly lets you use something up to date, plus you can use the latest version of the aws client libraries (1.11.77) instead of the ancient (1.7.5)

Comment: I left a lot of dependencies out. Sorry. I just updated the project.clj. However, your suggestion sounds like a good one. I will attempt to use the java lib using interop and not use the wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

This isnt an answer but I cant comment with my low reputation :(. The spelling for the 'apache' namespace seems to be wrong in the config

```
   org.appache.http=ERROR
   org.appache.http.wire=ERROR
   org.appache.http.headers=ERROR
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue,

creating a logback.xml and putting it on classpath with below config fixed it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="httpclient" level="ERROR" />
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps the others.